# How to differentiate $f(x) = 1-xe^{1-x}$ w.r.t. $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would like to differentiate the following with respect to $x$:

$$f(x) = 1-xe^{1-x} \tag 1$$

How would I do this please?  I can see that the 1 would disappear, then I am left with

$$-\frac{d}{dx}xe^{1-x}\tag2$$

If the initial $x$ wasn't there, I would just replace $1-x$ with $u$ and work it out that way, but the multiplicition by $x$ is confusing me.  If you explain using rules or some method that has a name please say so I can look it up also thank you.

Comment: You have to apply the product rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f'(x)=- e^{1-x}+xe^{1-x}$ it is just an application of the product  rule

PRODUCT RULE: if $f (x)=g(x)h(x)$,then $ f'(x)=g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x)$ now in our context $g(x)=x,\,h(x)=e^{1-x}$.

Comment: You did not differentiate the exponential correctly.

Comment: Yes! Thankyou, I accidentally put in an extra $x$, I have edited

Comment: Thank you, however when I do this I get $g'(x)=1$ so $g'(x)h(x)=e^{1-x}$ and then $h'(x)=-e^{1-x}$ which leaves $g(x)h'(x) = -xe^{1-x}$

Comment: Totally true, except we start off with a minus sign!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=g(x)+m(x)\cdot h(t(x))$, where:

$g(x)=1,$
$m(x) = x,$
$h(x)=e^x,$
$t(x)=1-x$

You have to apply the sum rule, product rule and chain rule.